# React native firebase I used cloud messaging navigate to screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-firebase

In my component class in `componentWillMount` method request permission and get token

```
  componentWillMount () {
     firebase.messaging().requestPermissions()
     firebase.messaging().getToken().then((token) => {

     })
  }
```

And after `componentwillMount` method in class level I place my `onMessage` and `getInitialNotification` methods so I want to navigate to another screen when I click notification. But I can't navigate to that screen.

```
    componentWillMount () {
     firebase.messaging().requestPermissions()
     firebase.messaging().getToken().then((token) => {

     })
    }

    firebase.messaging().getInitialNotification()
    .then(payload => {
      console.log('getInitialNotification', payload)
      if (payload.slug != undefined) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('notification');
      } else {

      }
    })

    firebase.messaging().onMessage((payload) => {
     if (!payload.opened_from_tray) {
      navigate(routes.Notification, 1)
     }
    })
```